# Android SQLite : Issue with delete statement prepared query

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android App, am trying to delete a row from SQLite. Sorry, am new to this & so may be asking something stupid. 
Earlier I was using this query for the deletion:

```
    String queryToExecute = "DELETE FROM " + Constants.TABLE_STATS
            + " WHERE " + Constants.COL_ID + " IN " + "(SELECT "
            + Constants.COL_ID + " FROM " + Constants.TABLE_STATS
            + " WHERE " + Constants.COL_NAME + " = '" + name
            + "' AND " + Constants.COL_ID_ONE + " = " + idOne
            + " AND " + Constants.COL_DB_ID + " = " + dbId
            + " ORDER BY " + Constants.COL_DATE + " DESC" + " LIMIT 1)";
    databaseConn.execSQL(queryToExecute);
```

But am trying to convert this to a parameterized query like this:

```
    String whereClause =        
            "? IN " + "(SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = '?' AND ? = " + idOne
            + " AND ? = " + dbId
            + " ORDER BY ? DESC" + " LIMIT 1)";

    String[] whereArgs = {Constants.COL_ID, Constants.COL_ID, Constants.TABLE_STATS, Constants.COL_NAME, name, Constants.COL_ID_ONE, Constants.COL_DB_ID, Constants.COL_DATE};
     int numOfRowsDeleted =
     databaseConn.delete(Constants.TABLE_STATS, whereClause,
     whereArgs);
```

But this is causing a crash saying

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ? IN (SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = '?' AND ? = 1 AND ? = 1 ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT 1)

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?` only to bind literals, not identifiers such as table or column names. When binding literals, the `?` must not be quoted itself (`'?'` is a string literal containing `?`, not a placeholder.)

I don't really see the point of attempting to use `delete()` if you already have a functioning `execSQL()` raw SQL. You can use `?` placeholders with `execSQL()`, too, for example for the string literals such as `name`.

Comment: Yes we can't use '?' for binding identifiers. It's better to go with execSQL()